# What are the applications of Weingarten calculus?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, quantum-information

Weingarten calculus is a general and explicit method to compute
the moments of the Haar measure on compact subgroups of matrix algebras<sup>1</sup><sup>,2</sup>. My gist is that it is somehow related to random matrix theory and random quantum states, but I don't really know.

What are the main applications of [Weingarten calculus](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=weingarten+calculus) in physics? If that is too broad, let's say just quantum physics.

There is no need to start to explain in detail what Weingarten calculus is, I am mostly interested in a bit of an overview on what one can do with it.

---

<sub>1. https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0205010

2. https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0402073</sub>